# Ajax - browser lag when updating content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to update a status page live.

I'm using Ajax to update the page. The update is set to update every 3 seconds. But whenever the update is being called the browser freeze at least for a second or two.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = updateStatus;

    function updateStatus() {
        updateinfo();
        setTimeout(updateStatus, 3000);
    }

    function getJson(theUrl, update) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                update(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function updateinfo() {
        getJson('backend/status', function(update) {
            var jsono = JSON.parse(update);
            document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = jsono.name;
            document.getElementById('online').innerHTML += jsono.online;
            document.getElementById('ip').innerHTML = jsono.ip + ':';
            document.getElementById('ip').innerHTML += jsono.port;
            document.getElementById('memory').innerHTML = jsono.memory + " MB";
        });

    }
</script>
```

If someone can give me tips on improving this. To make it less laggy or make it go away.

2) I have been thinking about using JQuery. Should I make the move? Pros and Cons? Also how is JQuery performance wise comparing to just JavaScript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are letting the AJAX request run synchronously - which you never ever need to so, since that prevents it from being AJAX in the first place, because the A stands for **asynchron**.

Change the third parameter of the `xmlhttp.open` call to `true` (or just leave it out, since that is the default).